# Chatter and HIPAA compliance - override chatter email notifications

Tags: email, chatter

Does anyone know if there is an ability to replace current chatter email notifications with custom ones?

We want the ability to post chatter messages that may contain information that is not acceptable to communicate over email. I'd like to standardize each notification to say "There has been a chatter post relevant to you. Click here to see the post" regardless of the content of the actual post.

I've seen ways to turn notifications off altogether, but nothing covering this use case.

Thanks,

K

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a simple, clean way to suppress the Chatter emails.  The approach you'll have to take is to disable the Chatter Emails settings of each user.  It would be simple enough to force the email settings in a trigger on the User object.  For the Chatter Group digests, you'd need to take the same approach in CollaborationGroupMember to force the email digest option to 'N' for Never.